# Find unitary such that $U:|i\rangle|0\rangle\rightarrow|i\rangle|A_i\rangle$

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, gate-synthesis, unitarity

Let's assume I have two qubits of state $|A_0\rangle$ and $|A_1\rangle$ correspondingly stored in a quantum memory. How do I find a Unitary $U$ that acts on another register of 2-qubits such that
$$U:|i\rangle|0\rangle\rightarrow|i\rangle|A_i\rangle?$$

Is such a unitary even possible or is this forbidden due to the no-cloning theorem? However, I don't want to clone the states $|A_0\rangle$ and $|A_1\rangle$, but rather do some kind of multiplexing with them.

That's what my register looks like:

[image]

In the end, I want to turn the $|0\rangle$ qubit into $|A_i\rangle$ depending on the state of the $|i\rangle$ qubit. Is something like this generally possible?

Comment: I should have clarified that. I'm looking for a circuit model of the above-mentioned Unitary, so the decomposition in terms of elementary gates is what I would need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is impossible, because it violates the no-cloning theorem. You want to implement the function
$$ |A_0\rangle|A_1\rangle|i\rangle|0\rangle \mapsto |A_0\rangle|A_1\rangle|i\rangle|A_i\rangle, $$
but if you could do that you could also clone, e.g. by fixing $i=0$, which would make the function be
$$ |A_0\rangle|A_1\rangle|i\rangle|0\rangle \mapsto |A_0\rangle|A_1\rangle|0\rangle|A_0\rangle, $$
which is cloning the state $|A_0\rangle$ and ignoring the state $|A_1\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do it! Here's the circuit:

[image]

The reason that the no-cloning theorem does not apply here is because you are  requiring precise inputs (in particular you are choosing your input qubit to be $|0\rangle$). A cloning would look like $|A_i\rangle|i\rangle|x\rangle \rightarrow |A_i\rangle|i\rangle|A_i\rangle$ for some arbitrary $x$ which would indeed be impossible.

Also if you would like the gates to be even more 'elementary', you can check you [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.0974) that describes how to construct CCNOT gates out of T gates.

**Edit: This only works if $A_i = \{0,1\}$, not for any arbitrary superposition (thank you Mateus Araújo for pointing that out)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! That produced the expected outcome for my code! Can you maybe elaborate a little bit on your reasoning behind the gate choices? I still struggle most to find the gate decomposition if I see a general unitary like $U:|\psi\rangle\rightarrow |\phi\rangle$.

Comment: I don't have a great intution on general unitary decomposition but I can comment about this specific one. First you want to ensure that 'if $i=1$, copy $A_1$'. That's always just a CCNOT gate (the final gate in the circuit). The other case was 'if $i=0$, copy $A_0$'. For any 'if $i=0$' statement, you can apply an $X$ gate on $|i\rangle$, use ctrl gates, and apply $X$ again.This was what was done first in the circuit.

Comment: No, this is completely wrong. The circuit only works if $|A_i\rangle$ is either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$. If you let it be $|+\rangle$ it will fail, for example. And the reason it cannot work is precisely that it would violate the no-cloning theorem.

Comment: Okay, now I'm wondering why my code still returns the expected behavior. In my case, $|A_i\rangle$ is a generic state in a random superposition.

Comment: @MateusAraújo: I am a little bit confused. I understand that the proposed circuit is in fact controlled fan-out which is used for "copying" qubits. Of course these qubits are not independend since $CNOT(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)|0\rangle = \alpha|00\rangle + \beta|11\rangle$. The proposed circuit works in the same manner but the fan-out is controlled by register $|i\rangle$. So, I do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: @Thommy257: I tried to construct the propsed circuit and it works for general state. See my explanation in comment above and answer below.

Comment: The probability of measuring 1 in the last qubit is $|\beta|^2$ in both cases. You'll see a difference when measuring in a basis other than the computational one. For example, if $|A_0\rangle = |+\rangle$, and you measure the last qubit in the X basis, the circuit will give 1 with probability 1/2, but it should give 1 with probability 1 if it was doing what the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run circuit proposed by *Rajiv* on IBM Q. In my case $|A_0\rangle = |+\rangle$, so probabilities of measuring 0 and 1 are 50 %. Then I set $|A_1\rangle = Ry(\pi/4)|0\rangle$ which means that probability of measuring 0 is 85 % and for 1 it is 15 %.

For setting $|i\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$, state $|A_0\rangle$ is returned to qubit $q_3$ and for setting $|i\rangle$ to $|1\rangle$, state $|A_1\rangle$ is returned to qubit $q_3$. Or in other words, I measured above mentioned probabilities on qubit $q_3$ for both settings of $|i\rangle$.

Here is a code:

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

qreg q[4];
creg c[1];

h q[0];
ry(pi/4) q[1];
x q[2]; \\put x for i = 1, remove this line for i = 0
x q[2];
ccx q[0],q[2],q[3];
x q[2];
ccx q[1],q[2],q[3];
measure q[3] -> c[0];
```

Concerning the no-cloning theorem. There is no violation of the theorem as the circuit proposed by *Rajiv* uses controled fan-outs which does not violate the theorem. See explanation [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9113/no-cloning-theorem-and-fan-out-gate).

EDIT: Original state $A_i$ and its "copy" are of course entangled and hence not independent as the "copy" is produced by fan-out.

Comment: Rajiv's circuit does not violate the no-cloning theorem simply because it is a valid quantum circuit, anything that can actually be done within quantum mechanics cannot violate the no-cloning theorem. The problem it that it does not do what the question asked, mapping $|A_0\rangle|A_1\rangle|i\rangle|0\rangle$ to $|A_0\rangle|A_1\rangle|i\rangle|A_i\rangle$.

Comment: @MateusAraújo: I see what you mean now. You can use the circuit by Rajiv but of course you cannot have two independent instances of $A_i$. They are entangled because they are produced by fan-out.